# How to use migrations with HMVC in CodeIgniter?

Tags: database, codeigniter, migration, hmvc

Could this be done or not?

Because when you are creating a classic migrations they are e.g. 001, 002, 003, etc.

but when you have multipple modules how would you create migrations for them.

Is this possible in Hierarchical MVC or not?

If yes how should I write me migrations?

Comment: Any idea how to do that?

Comment: We have a migrations folder in each module, with an install script and then individual migration files named with a timestamp to keep them in order.  It took a fair bit of custom code, and I think it was originally borrowed from Pyro CMS and modified.

Answer (score 0):

You can migrate MVC to HMVC using this modular extension

https://bitbucket.org/wiredesignz/codeigniter-modular-extensions-hmvc

Then just place the your MVC file in module-wise structure

There will be some changes for routes method as its will access like

`modulename/classname/methodname/paramters`(if required)

you can also change template engine to smarty will be easy to develop views

Comment: The question asked was how to use migration in HMVC. not how to migrate from MVC to HMC